# Angular child component view not getting update

Tags: angular, angular9

I have three component in the following structure. When I try to update the object property is not reflect in the view. Could you please help me what is the reason behind this.

app.component.html

```
<app-event (myNewFun)="sortList()" [myChild]=journey.course></app-event>
```

app.component.ts

```
 this.store$.pipe(select(selectObjectJourney), takeWhile(() => this.componentActive)).subscribe((result: Journey) => {
          this.journey = result;
        });
-----------
sortList() {
    this.journey.course = //doing some operation and updating the journey object but not getting reflect
  }
```

event.component.html

```
<app-child [myChildInside]="myChild"></app-child>
<button (click)="myFun()">Sort</button>
```

event.component.ts

```
@Input() myChild;
  @Output() myNewFun = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  myFun() {
    this.myNewFun.emit();
  }
```

child.component.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of myChildInside">
  <li>{{item.name}} --- {{item.mark}}</li></ul>
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input() myChildInside;
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Change detection in not triggered in component When you change the value of object. In order to trigger change detection you change the reference like this

**Try this:**

```
this.journey = { ...this.journey, course: this.journey.course.sort(sortPredicate('title', false, (title: string) => title && title.toLowerCase()))}
```

Comment: I will try, then i let u know. Thanks

Comment: `this.journey.course = this.journey.course.sort(sortPredicate('title', false, (title: string) =>  title && title.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: The above one is the code, how would do change detection, `this.journey` have many other properties